# How to open a file with Nios II

Tags: c, nios

iam currently using NIOS II with Quartus II v12.0

Since Nios II uses Language C, it would be allowed to open files, but the command fopen("filename","readmode"); is not avaiable for using, cause its not located on stdio.h from Nios, so my doubt is, how can I open a file in Nios? would I need to use a new library? will I have to change my codeblocks stdio.h to my Nios one?

Thanks for now.

Comment: What has Code::Blocks got to do with this?  Code::Blocks is an IDE not a compiler - it does not have a stdio.h - that belongs to whatever compiler you are using via Code::Blocks.  You need to use the version of stdio.h that is provided with the compiler for your target platform.  Do not use stdio.h from some other compiler; especially not a Windows target compiler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Demonstration project from DE2-115 DVD and got an FAT library, now I can open files.

Comment: Is it available for download? Can you elaborate how you did it? I got the DE2-115 and I want to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a look at the [Nios II Software Developers Handbook](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/n2sw_nii5v2.pdf&ei=D3NGUM8wx6bRBdb0gOAF&usg=AFQjCNFvJaKdwziCRvFcxwtmL9Eq0RNU8w&sig2=0Ut_SnB4xVROa4Xt9kB1tA&cad=rja), and see that uses the [Newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) C library, and the developer manual refers to fopen() so I can only assume that you are incorrect. Newlib is open-source, so you could investigate for yourself.

Even then Newlib library does not implement a file-system in any case - stdio is not a filesystem; rather it provides a standard interface to *any* stream I/O device.  The file-system itself is normally provided by an operating-system or third-party library.

Even if you have a file-system, you still have to provide the low-level interfacing between it and stdio in any case, via the Newlib [syscalls stubs](http://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls) in this case.

NiosII defines only the processor architecture, any file system hardware would be entirely proprietary, so it is not possible to have file-system support that works out of the box in any case - it would have to be adapted to your hardware.

What kind of device are you intending on creating a file-system on?  You might use a third-party library such as [EFSL](http://efsl.be) or [ELM FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html).  You could use them stand-alone or integrate them into stdio by implementing appropriate syscalls.